# Ubuntu Subdomains on the Fly

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, hyper-v, subdomain

We're a trying to accomplish the following on a Ubuntu Server 13.04 installation.

We host SaaS apps for customers are are currently moving off shared hosting environments due to limitations with resources and fats growth.

We'd like the best environment to host customer's web apps in a subdomain'ed environment. For example, customers purchase custom developer business apps from us. Their domain names could be anything from:

customer1.domain.com powerhouse.domain.com healthcare.domain.com

The domain.com represents our domain. We'd like to set up a single server to host a few customer apps. We'd like to do with without a plesk/cpanel environment if possible to save on cost. I have no idea where to start or to look. We have a LAMP server up (ubuntu as mentioned above) that hosts a single site perfectly fine. We'd like to host more than one though. We want a single IP address assigned to the box as well.

If anyone can provide direction or insight on this, that would be great.

Extra Info:

We use HyperV to manage a ubuntu instance.

Requirements:

Single IP per box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this all via HTTP/HTTPS? Assuming you are using Apache use the ServerAlias command. Apache will look at what site the browser is requesting and direct it to the appropriate site using "host header recognition"

You will set up one  for each customer.

Ideally you'd do this in (assuming Ubuntu/Debian) /etc/apache2/sites-availble/ ,one for each site and then softlink it to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. You can just create the file in the sites-enabled directory and have all the vhosts defined in it but it gets hard to read once you have a dozen or more set up.

Comment: Says I need httpd conf... Where is this file located?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Softlink it to sites-enabled seems confusing to me. just created a virtualhost in sites-available, going to test it now, should just work?

Comment: The sites-* part is so you can do stuff like remove a site in an orderly way with out losing the config if you want to put it back etc.